# How I can get a field based on a prefix in the awk print?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a file containing the following data:

```
toto,1,xsd:integer
titi,true,xsd:boolean
tata,str,attr,xsd:string
```

infact the format of each line is:

```
parameter_name,value,...,xsd:type
```

the parameter_name is fix and it's in the position 1. The value is also fix and it's in position 2. But the type position is variable it could at any postion except the position 2 and 1. but the type field contains always the prefix `xsd`.

Now I m trying to execute an awk to extract only the param name, the value and the type.
For the moment I m able to extract the param name and the value with

```
awk -F"," '{print $1"-"$2}'
```

But I m not able to extract the type field since its position is variable. How I can get the type field based on its prefix `xsd` in the `awk` output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj `xsd:integer` is the type on the first line

Comment: `awk '... your stuff ... ; myType=$0; sub(/.*xsd:/,"", type); print myType` ... ?  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the rest of the fields looking for the prefix.

```
awk -F, '{type="";
          for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) { if($i ~ /^xsd:/) { type = $i; break; } }
          print $1"-"$2"-"type; }'
```

Comment: what if the xsd:type is not present in the line? I think it will print a wrong type. I think that the type should be initiated in the awk. isn't?

Comment: I've added an initial value before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this GNU sed command,

```
$ sed -r 's/^([^,]*),([^,]*),.*(xsd:[^,]*).*/\1,\2,\3/g' file
toto,1,xsd:integer
titi,true,xsd:boolean
tata,str,xsd:string
```

OR

```
$ sed -r 's/^([^,]*),([^,]*),.*(xsd:[^,]*).*/\1-\2-\3/g' file
toto-1-xsd:integer
titi-true-xsd:boolean
tata-str-xsd:string
```